# How to parallelize armadillo in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, parallel-processing, armadillo

In my project, I am using **armadillo** with **Intel MKL** for my matrix operations in C++. I have activated **OpenMP** in **VS2017**, but my problem is armadillo does not work in parallel. When I check the core usage, only one core does calculations. Should I do some other configurations for armadillo?

Thanks

Comment: Did you define `ARMA_USE_OPENMP` when building it?

Comment: what is the typical problem sizes you are trying to solve? in the case of small inputs, the execution time may be too fast and too difficult to recognize how many cores/threads were occupied by computations. in the case if you use Intel MKL, you may set MKL_VERBOSE environment variables and see how many threads have been used by  MKL.

Comment: I have not used ARMA_USE_OPENMP. Could you please share example?

Comment: Problem size is not small. My matrix is 2000x2000, and it takes around 9 sec to find eigenvalue of this matrix.

Comment: Link with your Armadilo based programs with [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) or [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) instead of standard BLAS/LAPACK. This will give you parallelized eigen decomposition.

Comment: It is already linked with MKL. I followed this [link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/03/24/getting-started-armadillo-cpp-linear-algebra-windows-mac-linux/) for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem size is not too small. In this case, if Intel MKL has been called into a threaded mode, you may easier to check by setting the verbose for MKL ( export MKL_VERBOSE=1 environment variable ) and check the output. You may see something like as follows into output ( I used 2000x2000 example of SYEVD routine from LAPACK):
MKL_VERBOSE Intel(R) MKL 2019.0 Update 5 Product build 20190808 for Intel(R) 64 DSYEVD(V,U,2000,0x2b2fb3f75010,2000,0xf91f10,0x2b2fba13e080,8012001,0xfa7f80,10003,0) 466.55ms CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  **NThr:20**
 NTHR == 20 indicates that this is a threaded mode and dsyevd uses 20 threads.

Here is [the link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-using-intel-mkl-verbose-mode) which shows more details about this feature.